# Extract Arabic Text using iTextsharp get number only?

Tags: text, itext, extract, arabic-support

I try To extract Arabic  Text from PDF file but it extract only number and the result like this :

: 7234569 1439/08/07 : : 1 2375173941 14 08 6 39266 1050672243 2280 30 400 24 415 24 15 720 30 402 30 499 14 07 1 610117038085 0 1069508677 0 :

My code :

```
public static string GetTextFromAllPages(string pdfPath) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
    string result = null ;
    //for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    result = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy()); return result;
}
```

Any help Please?

Comment: Is the arabic text actual characters in the document or images?

Comment: How are you extracting it?

Comment: most likely your pdf does not contain the information required for text extraction. Or some error in your code. Thus, please share your pivotal code and your test pdf for analysis.

Comment: public static string GetTextFromAllPages(string pdfPath)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);

            string result = null ;

            //for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            result = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());

            return result;
        }

Comment: this my doc https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vnxMDTUn35pwXeKYrTW0_OtWIH8xLUaY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this link contains more than one doc you can test it  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v23BpumlBrAwNSM7TkdWxhq3JecWOLIG?usp=sharing

Comment: I try to get text from doc not image

Answer (score 0):

The embedded font for Arabic glyphs in your PDF contains this **ToUnicode** CMap:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
```

According to ISO 32000-1, section 9.10.3 *ToUnicode CMaps*:

> It shall use the **beginbfchar**, **endbfchar**, **beginbfrange**, and **endbfrange** operators to define the mapping from character codes to Unicode character sequences expressed in UTF-16BE encoding.

Unfortunately your CMap does not use these operators at all and, therefore, does not define any mappings to Unicode.

Furthermore the font has an **Encoding** of **Identity-H** and its descendant CIDFont has a ROS *Adobe-Identity-0* which means that character code, CID, and GID values are equal for a character but doesn't imply any mapping of them to Unicode.

Thus, the font is missing the information required for text extraction according to ISO 32000-1 section 9.10.2 *Mapping Character Codes to Unicode Values*.

*(In such a situation text extractors can only guess, and such guesswork usually only works for a special type of documents the extractor is optimized for. You might want to try to enhance iText to be able to guess correctly in your case but that will require you to study the PDF specification, the iText text extraction code, and your sample files in detail.)*

---

By the way, a good first test whether text extraction is feasible is to open the PDF in Adobe Reader and to copy and paste the text in question to an editor or word processor. If this does not work (and in the case at hand it does not work), chances are that the file does have incomplete or misleading information for text extraction (or none at all).

Comment: Very Good comment...Thank you